# Graylog2 Failed Upgrade

Tags: graylog2

We upgraded from graylog 2.1.3 to 2.3.2 and now receive this message repeatedly.  Some parts of the UI load but not Search or Streams.  Alerts are still going out.  Anyone now how I can fix this?  Rollback seems to not work at all.

```
Could not apply filter [StreamMatcher] on message <d8fa4293-dc7a-11e7-bc81-0a206782e8c1>:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: index set must not be null! (stream id=5a00a043a9b2c72984c581b6 title="My Streams")
```

Answer (score 0):

What seems to have happened is that some streams did not get the "index_set_id" added in their definition in the Streams Collection in mongo. Here is an example of a bad one:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a1d6bb2a9b2c72984e24dc0"),
    "creator_user_id" : "admin",
    "matching_type" : "AND",
    "description" : "EU2 Queue Prod",
    "created_at" : ISODate("2017-11-28T13:59:14.546Z"),
    "disabled" : false,
    "title" : "EU2 Queue Prod",
    "content_pack" : null
}
```

I was able to add the "index_set_id" : "59bb08b469d42f3bcfa6f18e" value in and restore the streams:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a1d6bb2a9b2c72984e24dc0"),
    "creator_user_id" : "admin",
    "index_set_id" : "59bb08b469d42f3bcfa6f18e",
    "matching_type" : "AND",
    "description" : "EU2 Queue Prod",
    "created_at" : ISODate("2017-11-28T13:59:14.546Z"),
    "disabled" : false,
    "title" : "EU2 Queue Prod",
    "content_pack" : null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue too with other version of Graylog in kubernetes environment.

I took below actions to fix this issue:

From **Graylog UI** under **Stream** menu, select **more actions** next to your stream, in your case its : **My stream** click > **edit stream** > select **"Default index set"** from drop down list.

Do it for all the available streams.